# What is the best strategy to handle type-related warnings in macros?

Tags: rust

I have defined a macro to gracefully handle out-of-bounds slicing. The following is the macro's definition:

```
macro_rules! slice_or_else {
    ($array: expr, $to:expr, $err: block) => ({
        if $to <= $array.len() {
            &$array[..$to]
        }
        else $err
    })
}
```

When I compile a function using it, the compiler complains that

```
warning: comparison is useless due to type limits, #[warn(unused_comparisons)] on by default
```

despite the fact that comparison is used determine whether the requested slice is valid, and that the macro passes testing. Am I missing something?  Can these warnings be turned off for macros?

---

**Update:** It appears that passing `0` as `$to` causes the problem, as Reem suggested. An example ([Playpen Example](http://is.gd/EzNUk6)):

```
fn main() {
    let a: [u8; 4] = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    assert!(slice_or_else!(a, 0, {return;}).len() == 0);
}
```

I am using macros because I want to be able to affect the flow of the calling function.

Since the warning is justified, what is the best strategy to deal with this use case? Binding `$to` to temporary variable? casting it explicitly?

Comment: I confess I know _nothing_ about rust, but is it possible that if $to is too long then `&$array[..$to]` it will throw an error anyways? If so, the error message would make sense (ie, the type will perform the comparison anyways).

Comment: @chessofnerd: `$to` is an integer cast-able to `usize` (The compiler insures this). The if statement assert that execution will not reach the `&$array[..$to]` statement unless $to is less the length of the array. So I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @chessofnerd: Explicitly casting `$to` seems to make the compiler happy. So that's one part of the problem solved.

Comment: Explicitly casting probably only silences the warning without fixing the problem, assuming there is one. Please give a working example (playpen) that produces the warning so we can figure out whether the warning is bogus. I suspect it only occurs when `$to` is constant, `$array` has a known length, or both.

Comment: Here is *one possible* reduced example of OPs macro: `fn main() { if 0 <= 0_usize { } }`

Answer (score 5):

If you use this macro with `$to` set to `0` then rustc will complain since `0 <= X` will always be true since we are working with `usize`, which is unsigned. Note that `&x[..0]` will never trigger an out-of-bounds error.

On a related note, here is a more idiomatic way to write this code:

```
fn slice_opt<T>(buf: &[T], ind: usize) -> Option<&[T]> {
     if ind <= buf.len() {
         Some(&buf[..ind])
     } else {
         None
     }
}

// Usage site                 // $err
slice_opt(x).unwrap_or_else(|| { &[] })
```

You should not use macros unless you *must* use a macro.

Things you need to use a macro for:

- new syntax
- return/break/continue from enclosing scope
- checked code generation
- some subtle type tricks (borrowing only one field of a type, &c.)

Things that you don't need to use a macro for:

- anything that could be a function (use functions)
- inlining (use #[inline])
- polymorphism/generics (use actual generics)

Comment: "new control flow structures" is a perfectly reasonable reason to use macros. It ensures that `return`/`continue`/`break` will work from the code the users passes into the control flow structure, which isn't true for closures.